# Kentico MVC - PageBuilder Error on external Staging site

Tags: asp.net-mvc, kentico

Am using Kentico MVC v12 Service Pack.

Have enabled Preview feature and PageBuilder in Application_Start.
When running from localhost, can successfully edit relevant pages using PageBuilder as required.

However, when ran from a staging site, which is a clone of the localhost version, I am getting an error in the Site settings when I try to add a Presentation Url (I am definitely adding in a valid format with the starting "https://" included), which is required for the PageBuilder to be used in the Pages application, where I see this error:

> An unexpected error occurred, see event log for more details. Event source: PageEdit, Event code PreviewLinkGeneration

Any assistance would be much appreciated.
Thanks.

[Sites error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LnZO4.png)

Comment: "see event log for more details"... what's the more details in the error log? You may get pointed in the right direction there?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That error is basically only looking at the string of the URL (almost like a simple validation). Are you sure there is no whitespace before the value you entered in? I can re-create your issue if I type in a space character before the URL.

You can also try clearing the field and saving the form. Then re-enter a value.

If it is still not working, try [re-signing all your macros](https://docs.kentico.com/k12sp/macro-expressions/troubleshooting-macros/working-with-macro-signatures#Workingwithmacrosignatures-Re-signingmacros) in the system as I have seen the regular expression validation rules have issues if macros aren't working. Which is really what this check is:

[image: Kentico Site class validation rules on Presentation URL]

Comment: The input was fine, but fixed this by re-signing macros again (even though they matched originally), along with switching some web farm / cache / restart application. Will give you point for answer Mcbeev as you are certainly towards the right path. Many Thanks.